# How to determine the permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

> In $S_6$, let $x=(1\  2\  3)$ and $y=(4\  5\  6)$. Find a permutation $z$ in $S_6$ such that $zxz^{-1}=y$.

I have done  it by checking all members of $S_6$ and I get $z=(1\  4)(2\  5)(3\  6)$. But it's tough to find such $z$ by checking all $6!$ elements, how to determine $z$ shortly, i.e. does there any logic to find $z$ in more scientific  manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the formula
$$
\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (\tau(a_1),\tau(a_2)\ldots \tau(a_k)) 
$$
for $k$-cycles, with $\sigma=(a_1,\ldots ,a_k)$. Take $k=3$. This gives $\tau(1)=4$, etc.

Comment: @Dietricch Burde,thank you sir,now I now 1 maps to 4,2 maps to 5,3 maps to 6,then need to check the mapping of $4,5,6$ from $3!$  members of $S_6$.Am I correct?

Comment: Here we have $z^{-1}yz=x$ and you can use the above again to see that $z(4)=1$ etc.